# Pandas read_excel with converter as 'str' reads capital TRUE as True

Tags: python, excel, pandas

On the image below left side - excel data, right - what resulting DataFrame contains.

PROBLEM: Capital TRUE(FALSE) is being replaced with True(False) even when I read all data as strings:

```
converter = {col: str for col in (0,1)}    
pd.read_excel(file, sheetname='Sheet1', index_col=None, header=None, keep_default_na=False, converters=converter)
```

I'd expect the col2 to contain the upper case values, but have True and False instead.
What am I doing wrong and how can I read TRUE as TRUE?
I want to read all values exactly as they're represented in excel. so TRUE should be TRUE, NA -> NA, True -> True, and all remaining an yet unknown special words

[image: example image]

Comment: Try passing `true_values=['TRUE','True']` to `read_excel`

Comment: What if there are other values which pandas interpret differently from their actual value? At least I found NA. How can I force pandas to disable all smart modification of data during reading?

Comment: That sounds like you want everything as strings.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. I want to read the entire table as cells with text

Comment: does passing `dtype=str` work?

Comment: dtype cannot be applied for python engine

Answer (score 0):

The following code works by creating a custom conversion function and assigning it to specific columns (only one in your case, but this could be expanded upon):

```
myconv = lambda x: str(x).upper()
bool_cols = [1]
converter = {col: myconv for col in bool_cols}    
pd.read_excel(file, sheetname='Sheet1', index_col=None, header=None, keep_default_na=False, converters=converter)
```

Comment: But this still means that I manually change the data during reading. I'd like to read the exact cell value without any modifications. What if I have TRUE and true in the same column? These are two different values

Comment: The exact cell value **is** a boolean value. You can check this for yourself with Excel's `TYPE` formula. If you want to store `TRUE` in Excel as a string, it needs to be prepended with a single quote -> `'TRUE`.

Comment: No, the type of a column is Text. And despite the Excel formula can convert it to boolean I want to read the exact value of a cell